# Multiple sharepoint web front end servers in Load balancer

Tags: 2010, load-balancing, f5

we have 4 web front end servers in our sharepoint farm and now plan for add these servers in load balancer F5,
for adding sharepoint web front end servers in load balancer there are settings need to do in IIS sharepoint wfe servers?

There are some sharepoint web applications working locally intranet level by some users and upload documents daily from different regions.

Answer (score 2):

All you need,point your DNS to load balancer and add all 4 wfe,s IP to load balancer.

When user make a request it lands on lb and thenLB will fwd it to wfe(as per their policy).

I don't think u need to make any change in IIS level. Just make sure, if you have any customization I.e change in web.config or 12 hive folder, should present on all wfe.

Comment: "change in web.config or 12 hive folder, should present on all wfe" i think sharepoint automatically does that sync job isnt it?

Comment: any manual changes will not be auto-populated...Like if you made a change manually into the web.config file. But if you made a change using the Solution/customization then it will auto populate.

Answer (score 2):

No need to change anything in IIS... just start the web application service on all WFEs and configure Alternate Access mapping the right way to avoid any problems later..then point the DNS of your portal (intranet.yourcompany.com) to the IP of Network Load Balancer (NLB) cluster.. and add your WFEs to the NLB cluster..thats it!